# Run multiple commands remotely using bash script

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I have to login to remote servers via ssh and go to tmp folder and there I have to run the rm command. But when i am executing the below script it goes to the to the remote server but do not go to temp folder and neither run the rm command.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat list`
echo $server
echo "------------------------------------------"
ssh $server << MYCOMMANDS
cd /tmp
rm log52.log
MYCOMMANDS
```

Comment: Did you run the script through https://www.shellcheck.net/? It contains typos.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute multiple commands remotely on few servers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273001/how-to-execute-multiple-commands-remotely-on-few-servers)

Comment: As an aside, `cd $dir; rm $file` is a dangerous antipattern.  Use `&&` to do the `rm` only if the `cd` succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

The only real issue with your code is that your loop lacks `do` and `done`, which would give you syntax errors, and that you are using `i` as your loop variable but try to connect with some `server` variable that may well be unset.

Apart from that, you are using `cat` in an unquoted command substitution which is *generally* a bad idea if you don't know for certain that you will be reading strings without whitespace and filename globbing characters (most hosts' names are well behaved in this respect though).

It's most of the time better to read the input line by line like so:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r remote; do
    ssh -n "$remote" 'rm -f /tmp/log52.log'
done <list
```

I'm using `ssh -n` here to stop `ssh` from reading its standard input stream (which would be connected to the `list` file).  Without `-n`, `ssh` would read the remaining contents of `list` and your loop would only run a single iteration.

Alternatively, if you really want to read the commands from a here-document:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r remote; do
    ssh -T "$remote" <<'END'
rm -f /tmp/log52.log
END
done <list
```

Here, I'm using `ssh -T` to explicitly disable pseudo-terminal allocation, which is not needed as we're not doing anything that requires user interaction.  I'm doing that because `ssh` will notice that its standard input stream has data, so it'll warn us about not having a functioning terminal on the remote system to do interactive things with.  We don't need `-n` with `ssh` here as we are reassigning the standard input stream for `ssh` from the here-document.

But the loop could be replaced by the single command

```bsh
xargs -I {} ssh {} 'rm -f /tmp/log52.log' <list
```

... where the `xargs` utility will read *lines* from the file `list`, replace `{}` in the `ssh` command with a line read from the file and perform the action of accessing the remote systems to delete the specific file.  I'm using `rm -f` to not cause an error if there is no file to delete.

Some implementations of `xargs` allows for parallel execution of the utility with e.g. `-P 4` (would keep at most four concurrent `ssh` commands going at once).

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
for i in `cat list`
do
    echo $i
    echo "-------------------------"
    ssh $i "rm /tmp/log52.log"
done
```

If you only need to remove the single file you may want to simply specify that in a one liner. Additionally, you may find it helpful to add `-f` to the `rm`.

Answer (score -2):

You can't simply redirect stdin of an ssh session like that.
You should be seeing an error message something like:

*Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal*

You need to use the option -tt to ssh to force a pseudotty to be allocated.
Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat list`
echo $server
echo "------------------------------------------"
ssh -tt $server << MYCOMMANDS
cd /tmp
rm log52.log
MYCOMMANDS
```

Comment: Both you and the OP seems to have forgotten the `do` and the `done` bit of the loop (consider _testing_ your own solutions). Also, a terminal should not be _needed_ as none of the commands are interactive.  In fact, using `-T` to explicitly _disable_ pseudo-terminal allocation will get rid of the warning (which, by the way, is just a warning).

Comment: True. These could be more easily passed as argument. I also forgot to mention that if you try to use a pseudotty/stdin redirection, when the here document completes it will leave stdin connected, so the list of commands should end with "exit" to exit the shell and disconnect. I think this is probably what the real issue is - it will execute on the first system, then hang because it doesn't disconnect from that system. On -T vs -tt I tend to tell people to use -tt and allocate the ptty so that it will work with commands that need one.

Comment: The connection with the remote host will terminate when the here-document has been redirected (at which point the remote shell receives end-of-file). An explicit `exit` should not be needed.

Comment: Not when I just tested it. (MacOS -> Linux)

Comment: You have not tested the script in your answer.

Comment: I did not test the script. I did test ssh with stdin redirection. The script in the original question is incomplete. I am not here to debug that. I don't understand why yolu don't apply yourself to answering the question if you can do so much better rather than nitpicking my responses.

Comment: I did answer the question.

Comment: @Philip The idea behind Stack Exchange is to collect high-quality Questions and Answers. The community here asks, answers, edits, and comments on posts in order to improve them or point out deficiencies. Your post could be improved by focusing the code only on the aspect that you're addressing (redirecting stdin for ssh) or by providing a complete replacement for the OP's script. I'd invite you to take our [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) for an introduction to the site and to browse the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for more background on how the site works.